# php variable in a select query

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I am pretty sure this is a syntax problem, but there may be other issues as well.

Ultimately, I'm trying to create a variable from an array that will be used in an insert statement, but I can't get past a select statement with a variable.

For a while I had `$country_id = $coun;` as `$country_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($coun);` but the `var_dump` suggested that the `mysql_real_escape_string` was preventing `$country_id` from taking on the value of `$coun`.

When I check for errors on `$q`, the query it spits out works just fine on `phpmyadmin`, yet the array outputs a NULL value.

I'm stumped.

Here is the code:

```
    //get short_name variable
        $country_id = $coun;
        //var_dump($coun, $country_id);
        $q = "SELECT short_name FROM country WHERE country_id = $country_id LIMIT 1";
        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
        $num = mysqli_num_rows($r);
        if ($num > 0) {//match was made
            //Get short_name
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);    
            //var_dump($row);           
        }else {
            echo '<p>no match</p>';
            }
```

Comment: You're not getting `no match`, right?

Comment: `country_id` is a number?

Comment: So PHP still doesn't have a debugger? Have you tried NetBeans?

Comment: Usual PHP debugging practice is to `echo` everything everywhere. Put an echo before each assignment. Then you'll see what goes wrong.

Comment: I am getting a match,  and country_id is a number. I just got some help and it turns out that the problem was that "assoc" should have been "array." it looks like this now. $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);.

Comment: However, as a noob, I'm not sure how to turn the result into a variable now. duh.

Comment: @OndraŽižka I'm not sure what you're talking about as [PHP debuggers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/debugger-about.php) have been around for quite some time. [Zend Debugger](http://www.zend.com/en/solutions/php-debugging/) [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) [APD](http://pecl.php.net/package/apd).

Comment: I was running var_dumps and this to debug $vquery = mysqli_query($q) or die(mysqli_error() . "\n<br>$q");

Comment: Congrats ;-) Close your question or answer for yourself. Or modify the question to match the current situation. Just to keep stackoverflow clean and neat place.

Comment: First question ever on the site. How do I close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got some help and it turns out that the problem was that "assoc" should have been "array." it looks like this now. `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);`